# Chrome 51.0.2704.103 Dev Tools Network Filter isn't filtering anymore

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, browser-link

I am accustomed to using the Filter field on the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools to filter out network requests - most notably, all the 'browserLink' network requests that show up when developing in Visual Studio.  In a recent Chrome update (current version I'm using is 51.0.2704.103) that stopped working.

The filter I used to apply is `-browserLink`, which has worked for a long time, but no longer filters out requests containing the text `browserLink`.

Did something in the filter format change, or is this a bug I should report?